# Make scatter plots for multiple subsets of data

Tags: r, plot

Let me introduce my data-set and my preliminary result first for better understanding my question. my dataset looks like:

```
Place      Species      Size      Conc.
 A           BT          24        0.2
 A           ST          76        1.4
 ...
 B           BT          45        1.2
 B           ST          21        0.7
 ...
```

I want to make scatterplot of `Size` against `Conc.` for each `Species` at each `Place`. What I have done uses `ggplot2` to make a graph as below:

```
scatterplot <- ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Size, y = Conc, color = Species)) + 
  geom_point(shape = 1)
```

Though this graph plots by the species group in different color, it summarizes all data in the dataset and fails to plot for different places.

I think the code below

```
scatterplot <- ggplot(mydata[mydata$place == "A"], aes(x = Size, y = Conc, color = Species)) + geom_point(shape = 1)
```

works for plotting just place `A` and I can do this for different places one by one. However, in my real dataset, the place variable has tons of different places, and I can't type them all out one by one manually. Thus my question actually is how to let R make those plots for different places  automatically at one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 ggplot(ddf)+geom_point(aes(Size, Conc.))+facet_grid(Place~Species)
```

[image]

If there are too many places:

```
ggplot(ddf)+geom_point(aes(Size, Conc., color=Place))+facet_grid(.~Species)
```

[image]

Or, in one graph:

```
ggplot(ddf)+geom_point(aes(Size, Conc., color=Place,shape=Species), size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, mso! It definitely works. one more question, since i have too many places. the final graph is squeezing together and hard to be read. I am wondering how to script to graph just part of places at one time? say the first 10 graphs.  or is there any other way to make the final graph looks better?  I can't attach my final graph due to low credit. sorry

Comment: You can sort the dataframe using command: ddf=ddf[order(ddf$Place),]. Then plot some places in one graph by specifying the rows: ggplot(ddf[1:10,]) rather than ggplot(ddf).