# Plotting Multiple Subsets of Data

Tags: r, plot, subset

I'm trying to plot Utilization by region (each state is in a given region), but don't know the best way of iterating through the data and eventually plotting all regions' utilization on the same graph.

```
PacificWest = pipeline[pipeline$State %in% c("WA","OR","CA"), ]
PacificWest

Yr.    Util.   State
2035    6       OR
2035    6       OR
2035    10      CA
```

It returns the correct subset rows of data, but I'm not sure how to automate the process of iterating through the data and somehow incorporating them into a for loop to then plot them.

Any insight is greatly appreciated!

-Trevor

Comment: This looks like `R` code but please add the tag of the programming language you are using. If you could provide the output of `dput(pipeline)` to your post (not comment) that would be very helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make scatter plots for multiple subsets of data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26600555/make-scatter-plots-for-multiple-subsets-of-data)

Comment: Through what would you like to iterate? States? One plot per state? What do you mean by eventually plotting all regions on the same graph? What tool do you use to plot these graphs?

Comment: Each state belongs to a specific region, so I'd like to have a function that says, "if state = ___, return "region___". There would ideally be one point for each state but it would be named by region, not state.